# ggbipolt from install_github() : Library(ggbiplot) does not load

Tags: r

There have been a number of articles about installing  from the github repository however when I try to install via  once I get past all the dependent packages (ggplot2, rlang etc) I still receive the error

"Error in process_initialize(self, private, command, args, stdin, stdout,  : 
  Command not found"

I seemed to have uploaded and loaded via library all the dependent files - the last of which was ggplot2. the code below shows this loading via . I want to use ggbiplot for some pca analysis - many examples of which use ggbiplot.

Any help appreciated

> install_github("vqv/ggbiplot")
>   Downloading GitHub repo vqv/ggbiplot@master
>   These packages have more recent versions available.
>   Which would you like to update?

1:   ggplot2 (3.1.0 -> 3.1.1) [CRAN]

Enter one or more numbers separated by spaces, or an empty line to cancel
1: 1
ggplot2 (3.1.0 -> 3.1.1) [CRAN]
Installing 1 packages: ggplot2
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/ggplot2_3.1.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 3621733 bytes (3.5 MB)
downloaded 3.5 MB

package ‘ggplot2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpA1EFhV\downloaded_packages
Error in process_initialize(self, private, command, args, stdin, stdout,  : 
  Command not found
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir) :
  skipping pax global extended headers
2: In untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir) :
  skipping pax global extended headers

> library(ggplot2)
>   Warning message:
>   package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 3.5.3
>
> library(ggplot2)
>
> library(ggbiplot)
>   Error in library(ggbiplot) : there is no package called ‘ggbiplot’
>
> install_github("vqv/ggbiplot")
>   Downloading GitHub repo vqv/ggbiplot@master
>   Error in process_initialize(self, private, command, args, stdin, stdout,  : 
>     Command not found
>   In addition: Warning messages:
>   1: In untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir) :
>     skipping pax global extended headers
>   2: In untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir) :
>     skipping pax global extended headers